# ImportError: cannot import name 'imresize' from 'scipy'?

Tags: python, scipy, conv-neural-network

I am using scipy but getting this error again and again. I used PILLOW and still got the same error.

**This is my code**

```
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise
from keras.models import load_model
from scipy import imresize
import PIL
#from PIL import Imageresize as imresize
#from skimage.transform import resize
```

```
def getPredictedClass(model):

    image = cv2.imread('Temp.png')
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_image = imresize(gray_image, [100, 120])

    gray_image = gray_image.reshape(1, 100, 120, 1)

    prediction = model.predict_on_batch(gray_image)

    predicted_class = np.argmax(prediction)
```

Answer (score 0):

From scipy github [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v1.3.0rc1) (it has been removed since 1.3.0)

```
Functions from scipy.interpolate (spleval, spline, splmake,
and spltopp) and functions from scipy.misc (bytescale,
fromimage, imfilter, imread, imresize, imrotate,
imsave, imshow, toimage) have been removed. The former set has
been deprecated since v0.19.0 and the latter has been deprecated since v1.0.0.
Similarly, aliases from scipy.misc (comb, factorial,
factorial2, factorialk, logsumexp, pade, info, source,
who) which have been deprecated since v1.0.0 are removed.
SciPy documentation for v1.1.0 <https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/misc.html>__
can be used to track the new import locations for the relocated functions.
```

You can either downgrade scipy or follow the steps [here](https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis/issues/209#issuecomment-586396612)

in `vis/visualization/saliency.py`

replace: `from scipy.misc import imresize`

to: `import cv2`

then

```
replace: heatmap = imresize(heatmap, input_dims, interp='bicubic', mode='F')
```

to:

```
heatmap = cv2.resize(src=heatmap,
                       dsize=input_dims,
                       interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```